# Windows batch script to recursively extract specific files using 7zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, extract, directory-structure, 7zip

I have a Directory with multiple `.tar` files which have multiple `.zip` files.  The tree structure is somewhat of this sort:

```
testDirectory
    -tarArchive.tar
        -directory1
            -zipArchive11.zip
                abc.XML
                1.TIF
                2.TIF
                ...
            -zipArchive12.zip
                xyz.XML
                a.TIF
                b.CDX
                ...
            .
            .
            .
        -directory2
            -zipArchive21.zip
                ...
            -zipArchive22.zip
                ...
            .
            .
            .
        .
        .
```

I need a single batch script to recursively extract only `.XML` from each `.zip` while maintaining the tree structure(first all `.zip` will be extracted from main `.tar` and then only `.XML` from each `.zip`).  Additionally,  the processed archives should be deleted afterwards.

I am able to achieve most of it with this code

```
for /R "C:\Users\frozenfyr\Desktop\test" %%I in ("*.zip", "*.tar") do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" && del "%%~fI"
)
```

except 2 things:

1. I'm unable to extract `.XML` files only.

   `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI"`**`"*.zip" -r`** will 
   not extract XML files and 
   `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI"`**`"*.XML" -r`**
   doesn't(shouldn't) work because nothing will match in `.tar` file. 
   Is there a way to do something like 
   `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI"`**`"*.zip" "*.XML" -r`**
2. The main `.tar` file is not deleted after processing.  I tried this
   script on `.zip` files and it works(they are deleted after
   processing).

I already tried a [powershell script](https://superuser.com/questions/770255) but I'm not very satisfied with it.  I feel batch script is easy for me to handle.  I even found a [post on SU](https://superuser.com/a/322233/243637) but it doesn't speak of multiple specific formats/files.  I read [Command Line Version User's Guide](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/) and considered [`-x` switch](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm) but it's not useful.

I can't quote all the references here but I did go through a lot of SO and SU posts and Google was probably not my friend this time.  I'm not sure whether SO or SU should be the place to ask this question,  I found good references on both communities.  I use SO more often so I'm here.

Please help me,  this is driving me crazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to solve my 1st problem.  The second one looks like a little complicated.  The `del` command works on archives of smaller size.  Because my `.tar` is huge(>1GB),  I think the next loop starts to execute before the command could delete the archive.  It would be good for me if not anyone else to have an answer here as a guide for future.

Anyway,  for the first problem,  I found out that I will need to do recursive with switch `-x` i.e., `-xr` and because I had multiple extensions that I wanted to skip,  I had to create `ignore.txt` and add all the exceptions there.  My complete script looked like this:

```
for /R "C:\Users\frozenfyr\Desktop\test" %%I in ("*.zip", "*.tar") do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -xr@"C:\Users\frozenfyr\Desktop\ignore.txt" -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" && del "%%~fI"
)
```

If i had just one extension that I wanted to ignore,  I'd do `-xr!"*.extension"` instead of `-xr@"C:\Users\frozenfyr\Desktop\ignore.txt"`

By the way,  `-xr` does not stop 7zip from processing the excluded files,  it probably deletes them after extracting because I saw `extracting abc.TIF` on command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

```
7z e -an -air!*.rar -r -oF:\target
```

extracts all tar files from the current directory's sub folders (recursively) into the target folder F:\target.

Comment: Haven't tried this but it looks pretty clean if it really works for what I wanted!

Comment: Well, why don't you give it a shot :)

Comment: 1. Busy on some other project,  2. Haven't got test file readily.  If I get a chance to test this successfully, I'll update my solution to link to yours appropriately. Pardon for sounding so reluctant PEACE :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a zipfile recursively, I am using "Swiss File Knife". In case you have the possibility to install other software on your system, this might be an idea?